# Azure Deployment Center - scripting

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, cicd, azure-bicep

I'm building Azure Function (Premium plan) with Private endpoint.

As I'm using private endpoint, function is not available from the public internet / MSFT managed Cloud pipelines.

Now, idea was to use Deployment Center in Function App to enable CI/CD, but I'm failing to find a way how to script configuration of Deployment Center.

Is there even a way to setup Deployment Center configuration outside of Azure Portal? Using Bicep or Powershell? Essentially, something which will map repository/branch/build pipeline with given slot.

It will be weird to have completely automated process for deployment of infrastructure and then to go there and manually update deployment configuration for each subscription/stage.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? I'm stuck on this as well. I'm needing to setup a function app with Terraform, but I haven't found a way to configure the "Deployment Center". All examples seem to require this to be done via the portal, which is not an option for us.

Answer (score 0):

you can use github actions to deploy the function, but you have to connect the github to the function through the deployment center.

This is simple process where in deployment center just select github under source and connect the github repository by Loging in the github account.

Another solution would be to use visual studio like tool to directly deploy from to development environment.

Also, you can containerize the function and deploy the container.

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-technologies) on all the ways of deployment to the azure.

Comment: Thanks, but that was not the question. Question was how to script deployment center configuration or is there any powershell script which can configure it.

Comment: Simple or not, this requirement to manually setup the SCM through the portal is a very poor design. They should provide some way to automate or script this.